# Customizable iOS Message Composer

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sms

I'm trying to replicate the iOS SMS Composer, but I need to change the data source for the contacts that are recognized and that are converted into the little blue things. They shouldn't be loaded from the phone's contacts, and I'm retrieving that data via JSON.

Are there any libraries out there that do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.
However, there is a library called Three20 which has a custom Message Composer (TTMessageController). That allows pointing the data source to a JSON data.

http://three20.info/

Comment: Do you know how to set the DataSource for this? The documentation is terrible. I got the Composer to come up and everything, but I can't seem to get it to load the contacts...

Comment: If you ask me, the best way is to write it all from scratch. Customizing Three20 is a PITA. I wouldn't recommend it unless you are running on a tight schedule.